# Как распределить полученный ответ PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Есть константа **`$donate1`**, которая в итоге выдает **`STEAM_X:Y:Z`**, мне надо подсчитать за формулой через PHP **`Z*2+Y=W`** и отправить в БД запрос с **`W`**, если находит значение- отправляет ответ с другой ячейки.
(Надо хоть помощь с PHP, с MySQL постараюсь и сам разобраться)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала отрезаем часть `STEAM_` с помощью функции `$str = substr("STEAM_X:Y:Z", 0, strlen("STEAM_")-1);`. Далее создадим массив из `X`, `Y` и `Z` с помощью функции `$arr = explode(":", $str);`. Теперь мы создадим саму формулу: `$W=intval($arr[2])*2+intval($arr[1]);`. Функция `intval()` переводит строковую переменную в целочисленную.

Документация по функциям:

1. [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.substr.php)
2. [`strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strlen.php)
3. [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php)
4. [`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.intval.php)

Comment: Вообще-то при проведении арифметических операций значения будут автоматически приведены в цифры, так что `intval` очевидно лишний.

Comment: Навсякий случай можно :)